# ScrollTo not working on initial load in new browser and incognito mode

Tags: javascript, scroll, carousel, pageload, scrollto

In the script I've written something like this: `carousel.scrollTo({left: slideWidth*1.5});` What this does is giving the carousel initial scroll when the page loads. The problem is, when entering the website from a new browser or in incognito mode, on the initial load carousel is not scrolled. It works only after the refresh or when it's not the first time that browser is used to access that site.

You can check site demo here (Note: it is currently not responsive and is only for mobile screens):
https://noiseymur.github.io/canvas-store/